# Inability to add label to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to follow [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18) tutorial: Add two labels to a `UITableViewCell`.

```
10. Drag objects from the Library onto the cell.

For this example, drag two label objects and position them
near the ends of the cell (leaving room for the accessory view).
```

When I create the TableView as a `Table View Controller` everything works fine. I can drag a label from the library to the cell.

However, when I create the TableView as part of a more general `View Controller` I am not able to drag a label from the library to the cell.

To replicate:

1. Drag a new `View Controller` from the library into the story board.
2. Drag a `Table View` from the library into the new View Controller. Leave default settings. Make sure one prototype cell exists.
3. Try to drag `Label` (or any other object) from the library into the prototype cell of the Table View. Impossible.

Doing step 1 and 2 combined by using a `Table View Controller` from the library makes step 3 possible.

So, how can I get my label into the prototype cell?

Comment: What you describe in your 3 steps works fine when I do it. What do you mean by "Make sure one prototype cell exists"? Do you actually drag one in?

Comment: @rdelmar I meant increase the prototype cell count in the inspector module by one.

Comment: I just followed your steps and incremented the prototype count to 3. I found I could add a label to cells 2 and 3 but not 1, which seems strange.

Comment: @Lyssa, exactly! I also added a few and then I reduced it again and now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually dragging a Prototype Cell from the library to the Table View makes later adding of labels possible.

[I am going to accept this answer if no one else answers. If you know why this is or can tell me what I did wrong (I'll gladly provide more info), I am happy to accept your answer.]

Comment: Until you drag one in, there is no cell to add a label to. When you drag in a table view, it's empty -- it has no cells.

Comment: Under Attributes inspector> Prototype Cells I put a 1. This adds a cell. See also Lyssa's comment.

Comment: Yeah, I see the same behavior that @Lyssa sees. It looks like just increasing the prototype cell count adds a cell, but it has no content view (but the 2nd, 3rd, etc. do). This looks like a bug in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. For now I solved this way:
Main.Storyboard -> on the bottom left there is button: Hide or show document outline.

So, I opened the Document outline and revealed all elements. Found the exact element where I want to add my objects and dragging from lebel from the left directly to the document outline object where I need. Then I couldn't move it, but I could resize it as I wanted.